# Jacobson radical and bimodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I know that the Jacobson radical of a (non-commutative) rng $R$ is the intersection of all annihilators of right irreducible modules. I know also that one can replace "right" with "left" in the previous definition. What if we consider the intersection of all annihilators of irreducible bimodules? Is this still the Jacobson radical of $R$?

By the annihilator of a bimodule $M$ I mean the largest ideal $A$ of $R$ such that $MA=0$ and $AM=0$.

Comment: What’s the annihilator of a bimodule? Elements annihilating the bimodule both on the left and on the right?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I (implicitly) thought that would be natural generalization

Comment: I’m not so sure.  You can view any R bimodule as a right $R\otimes R^{op}$ module, and that has its own annihilator, which might be more natural.

Comment: Or it could mean the x’s for which $xMx=\{0\}$, which may be strictly greater than what I mentioned in the first comment.  I think you’d better make it explicit in the post.

Comment: @rschwieb I made it clear in the post, I think that definition I what I was thinking about

Comment: @W4cc0 The problem with the definition you added is that the existence of the object defined is not justified at all: you speak of **the** ideal with such and such properties, without arguing it is unique. The null ideal clearly satisfies the relations you mention, there might be others. There is a *maximum* one, which is none other than the intersection of the two lateral annihilators. Nevertheless, how should one interpret your ambiguous definition?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I meant the largest one.